# phpquery equivalent that uses MXLReader?

Tags: php, xmlreader, phpquery

[phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) uses the [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) extension. Is there an equivalent to phpQuery that uses [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php)(with at least some of the functionalities in phpQuery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent to phpQuery that uses XMLReader?

No.

Comment: Do you think that such a library would be of use?